# Keyed directive does not respond to attribute change

Tags: lit

I am trying to use the keyed directive in lit element. I don't want to do the `?action=${action}` because just adding the `action` attribute or removing the `action` attribute is cleaner for true or false. However, the keyed directive does seem to reset the element when I add or remove the `action` attribute. Any ideas, please, on how to make this work without the hacky `?action=${action}`?

```html
      ${keyed(this.active, html`                                                                                          
        <add-transaction                                                                                                    
          @add-catergory=${() => this.openAddCatergory()}                                                                   
          @save-trans=${this.#saveTrans}                                                                                    
          .label=${this.label}                                                                                              
          id="add-transaction"></add-transaction>`)}
```

```js
  _loadNewTransactionPage() {
    const el = this.renderRoot.querySelector('#add-transaction');
    el.setAttribute('active', '');
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`keyed()` has nothing to do with, and knows nothing about, attributes. The key is any JS value (not necessarily even a property of an element) and if it changes the template instance is cleared and re-rendered.

If you *do* want to key off an attribute, you need to pass an attribute value to `keyed()` and you need to re-render when that attribute changes. Lit's reactive properties will do just that. So make a reactive property out of `action` (presumably it's "action", but you also use "active" in your code).

```
class MyElement extends LitElement {
  @property() action;

  render() {
    return html`
      ${keyed(this.action, html`                                                                                          
        <add-transaction                                                                                                    
          @add-catergory=${() => this.openAddCatergory()}                                                                   
          @save-trans=${this.#saveTrans}                                                                                    
          .label=${this.label}                                                                                              
          id="add-transaction"></add-transaction>`)} 
    `;
  }
}
```

Now when `action` changes on a MyElement, the template will re-render and the new value of `this.action` will be used as the key.

This in only combining reactive properties with `keyed()`. Again, `keyed()` can be used with any value from anywhere.